# MacOS: Change the profile of terminal app based on whether dark theme is on

Tags: macos, terminal

I am trying to write a script in `.zshrc` to switch the profile of terminal app based on whether Mac is dark mode or not.
Seems like this functionality is already implemented for Basic profile which is the default profile of MacOS. For the profile, if you toggle dark mode, the background becomes dark and white for Light mode.
I would like to do the same thing with different profile specifically for Solarized theme.

Yet, I can not find a shell command to switch the profile and to detect the current theme mode (light or dark).